# Programmatic Querying of Google and Other Search Engines With Domain and Keywords

Tags: seo

I'm trying to find out if there is a programmatic way to determine how far down in a search engine's search results my site shows up for given keywords. For example, my query would provide my domain name, and keywords, and the result would return a say 94 indicating that my site was the 94th result. I'm specifically interested in how to do this with google but also interested in Bing and Yahoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There is no programmatic access to such data. People generally roll out their own version of such trackers. Get the Google search page and use regexes to find your position. But now different results are show in different geographies and results are personalize.

`gl=us` parameter will help you getting results from US, you can change geography accordingly to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating this from scratch, you may want to save yourself some time (and money) by using a service that does exactly that [and more]: [Ginzametrics](http://www.ginzametrics.com).

They have a free plan (so you can test if it fits your requirements and check if it's really worth creating your own tool), an API and can even import data from Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising, but I'm still interested to know what is involved in getting programmatic access directly to the search engines.

Comment: If you find out, make sure to post on your question, I would be curious as well :-)